# specify a path for output which differs from the envi setting

Tags: python

Now i have these codes to get all shapefiles in DB_path1 (path of a database) and use one field to dissolve all files:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'DB_path1'

fclist=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for file in fclist:

   output=file+'_dissolved'

   arcpy.Dissolve_management(file, output, ["field"], "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

so after running the codes I will have many dissolved files in DB_path1, but now I want put the output in a different database say DB_path2. Is there anyway I can do it by editing the output such as:

```
output='DB_path2'+file+'_dissolved'
```

I tried it but it always failed and seems the path name and string together will cause confusion. Is there any solution? 
Tks for any tip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the code should look like:

```
 output = "DB/_path2/" + file + '_dissolved'
```

need double quotation around path, use forward slash / and in the end add a slash.